# In C#, Replace "\\" to "\"

Tags: c#, replace

I have a string:

```
var path = "d:\\project\\Bloomberg\\trunk\\UI.Demo\\";
```

I am trying to replace `\\` to `\`.

I've tried this:

```
path = path.Replace("\\\\", "\\");
path = path.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
```

None of those replaces the double backslashes with single backslash.

Comment: Why are you trying to replace \\ with \ ? \ is an escape character so \\ is to all intent & purpose \

Comment: @Ilya That string is fine, you don't need to do anything with it to use it in file handling code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `path` doesn't contain any double backslashes. `"blah\\blah"` is actually `blah\blah`.

In normal string literals (those not starting with an `@`), you need to escape some characters by putting a backslash (`\`) in front of them. One of those characters is the backslash itself, so if you want to put one backslash into a string, you escape it with another backslash, which is why `path` contains all those double backslashes. At runtime, those will be single backslashes.

See here for the available escape sequences: [C# FAQ: Escpape Sequences](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available.aspx)

Verbatim Strings (thos starting with an `@`) on the other hand, don't require escaping for most of those characters. So `@"\"`actually is `\`. The only characters you need to escape in a verbatim string are quotes. You do this by just typing a double quote. So `@""""` is actually `"`.

So if you wanted to put `d:\project\Bloomberg\trunk\UI.Demo\` into a string, you have two possibilities.

Normal String literal (note that `\` is escaped):

```
var path = "d:\\project\\Bloomberg\\trunk\\UI.Demo\\";
```

or verbatim string literal (no need to escape `\`):

```
var path = @"d:\project\Bloomberg\trunk\UI.Demo\";
```

Answer (score 2):

you do not forget to put @? front of your chain said ?

```
var path = @"d:\\project\\Bloomberg\\trunk\\UI.Demo\\";
```

But that -> @"d:\project\Bloomberg\trunk\UI.Demo\";
 is egal -> "d:/project/Bloomberg/trunk/UI.Demo/";

Answer (score 1):

in this string the `\\` are escapes for `\`:

```
var path = "d:\\project\\Bloomberg\\trunk\\UI.Demo\\";
```

so this actually says:

```
@"d:\project\Bloomberg\trunk\UI.Demo\"
```

So when you replace `\\` with `\` you're not replacing anything. double slashed would look like `\\\\` in normal strings. Which you did correctly in your replace method.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
var path = "d:\\project\\Bloomberg\\trunk\\UI.Demo\\";
```

to:

```
var path = @"d:\\project\\Bloomberg\\trunk\\UI.Demo\\";
```

and you will be good. Remember that `\\` means `\` in normal strings, so if you want actual double backslashes you need to use `\\\\` or simply prefix your string with @ - just like in your calls to Replace.

Secondly, as it is you probably don't need to call Replace in your particular situation since those `\\` you see actually are single backslashes since your string is not prefixed with @, and the escape sequences are evaluated.

Comment: "You will be good" implies that the first string is incorrect. The first string is fine and can be used in file handling code without issue.

Comment: I kind of realized my explanation may have been interpreted as such - hence my second paragraph.